# Cannot get 'download_count', or any assets, from assets list in github API for a release on a public repo

Tags: github-api

I want to count the downloads for a release on a public repo. The documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#list-release-assets
indicates that the assets request below should have a variable `"download_count:"`.

This is what I get for my small public test repo in a newly created test organization with 2 known downloads for the release v1.0:

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/tags/v1.0`

The response is:

```
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/tag/v1.0",
  "id": 34859773,
  "author": {
    "login": "breckbaldwin",
    "id": 6377185,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYzNzcxODU=",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6377185?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/breckbaldwin",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTM0ODU5Nzcz",
  "tag_name": "v1.0",
  "target_commitish": "main",
  "name": "Test Count Downloads",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2020-12-04T23:28:39Z",
  "published_at": "2020-12-04T23:29:18Z",
  "assets": [

  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/tarball/v1.0",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/zipball/v1.0",
  "body": ""
}
```

So I am getting the data on the release, but note that the assets list is empty. I run the explicit request for the assets as indicated in the documentation (this url is also supplied in the return data above):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets
```

This returns an empty list:

```
[

]
```

Adding in my authorization token and looking at return headers with -i as follows:

```
curl -i -u breckbaldwin:$github_token https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 23:44:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
ETag: "7ac3b1740ea68a78ed14bc8d160dae63ad1710fffb20a10910ae02fff4661e1d"
X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:enterprise, admin:gpg_key, admin:org, admin:org_hook, admin:public_key, admin:repo_hook, delete:packages, delete_repo, gist, notifications, repo, user, workflow, write:discussion, write:packages
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4990
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1607125659
X-RateLimit-Used: 10
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
X-GitHub-Request-Id: AE6A:5AF5:108649D:1BE42F1:5FCAC9CF

[

]
```

Still no `"download_count:"`. I am expecting an assets list that looks like (from the documentation for a different repo):

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/assets/1",
    "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example.zip",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDEyOlJlbGVhc2VBc3NldDE=",
    "name": "example.zip",
    "label": "short description",
    "state": "uploaded",
    "content_type": "application/zip",
    "size": 1024,
    "download_count": 42,
    "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
    "uploader": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    }
  }
]
```

Note the `"download_count": 42,` which is the variable I am looking for.

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Breck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I contacted github tech support and they were very quick and helpful.

- The automatically generated tarballs/zipballs when you do a release are NOT tracked for number of downloads period even though they are listed as an asset on the website. They are apparently generated on the fly.
- You can add a binary file to your release by generating the release, navigating to it and selecting the 'Edit Release' button on the top right. Scroll down to 'Attach binaries...' and add a file.

Now the asset is going to be tracked, so the old failed query:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/tags/v1.0
```

produces:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/tags/v1.0
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/34859773/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/tag/v1.0",
  "id": 34859773,
  "author": {
    "login": "breckbaldwin",
    "id": 6377185,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYzNzcxODU=",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6377185?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/breckbaldwin",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTM0ODU5Nzcz",
  "tag_name": "v1.0",
  "target_commitish": "main",
  "name": "Test Count Downloads",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2020-12-04T23:28:39Z",
  "published_at": "2020-12-04T23:29:18Z",
  "assets": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/assets/29251257",
      "id": 29251257,
      "node_id": "MDEyOlJlbGVhc2VBc3NldDI5MjUxMjU3",
      "name": "docs.txt.gz",
      "label": null,
      "uploader": {
        "login": "breckbaldwin",
        "id": 6377185,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYzNzcxODU=",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6377185?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/breckbaldwin",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "content_type": "application/x-gzip",
      "state": "uploaded",
      "size": 56,
      "download_count": 2,
      "created_at": "2020-12-07T13:48:49Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-12-07T13:48:50Z",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/download/v1.0/docs.txt.gz"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/assets/29252040",
      "id": 29252040,
      "node_id": "MDEyOlJlbGVhc2VBc3NldDI5MjUyMDQw",
      "name": "Figure.1.pdf",
      "label": null,
      "uploader": {
        "login": "breckbaldwin",
        "id": 6377185,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjYzNzcxODU=",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6377185?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/breckbaldwin",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/breckbaldwin/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "content_type": "application/pdf",
      "state": "uploaded",
      "size": 223221,
      "download_count": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-12-07T14:08:23Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-12-07T14:08:23Z",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/test10010000/countMyReleases/releases/download/v1.0/Figure.1.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/tarball/v1.0",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/test10010000/countMyReleases/zipball/v1.0",
  "body": ""
}
```

I have both a gzip and pdf in there.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader how to hack this capability into something useful.

Breck